# Why gulp jshint task execute two times?

Tags: gulp

Here is gulpfile.js:

```js
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    jshint  = require('gulp-jshint'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('jshint', function(){
  gulp.src('app/scripts/*.js')
      .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('app/index.html')
      .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('app/index.html', ['html']);

  gulp.watch('app/scripts/*.js', ['jshint']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function(){
  connect.server({
    root: 'app',
    port: '9001',
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['jshint', 'serve', 'watch']);
```

When I edit my `app/scripts/*.js`, the `jshint` task will run two times. Why? Is there anything wrong in my `gulpfile.js`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your default task is the responsible.

It execute jshing task (1 time so far), then serve task (ok) and finally watch, which will execute jshint again.

If you already passed jshint to your files, maybe you should remove jshint task from default's task, and create another one that is not watching, so you execute that task only once, and the you can just watch for new files.